# using css transition on rollover of another element

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background positioned absolutely on top of an image. When I roll over the div it changes colors using css3 transition.

But What I wanted to know is it if it was possible to roll over either the image, or the div and have it change colors either way?

```
<a href="http://localhost/">
      <div style="width:233px; float:left; position:relative; margin-right:17px; margin-bottom:20px;  ">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:213px; height:20px;  display:block; float:left; color:#fff; padding:10px; " class="category_roll">Camouflage Work Pants </div>

        <img src="images/cat_camo_pants.png" alt="Camouflage Work Pants" title=" Camouflage Work Pants " width="233" height="156">
      </div></a>
```

css:

```
.category_roll {
-webkit-transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.24s ease-out 1s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.24s ease-out 1s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.24s ease-out 1s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.24s ease-out 1s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.24s ease-out 1s ease-in-out 0s;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.category_roll:hover {background: rgba(201, 135, 2, 0.95);}
```

is this something that would require javascript?

Comment: Just include the class `category_roll` on the img attr as well. That will make the hover effect appear there as well. http://jsfiddle.net/fNac3/

Comment: I want to make the top bar change to orange when rolling over the image not the image. So only the top bar should be changing. Which means I need to reffrence the category_roll div from teh image somehow

Comment: ok i will change the code to suit your needs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is what I have come out with. It needs [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

**JS :**

```
$( "#img" ).hover(
    function() {
        $("#topBar").addClass("category_roll").css('background', 'rgba(201, 135, 2, 0.95)');
    }
);

$( "#img" ).mouseout(function() {
     $("#topBar").css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)');
});

$( "#topBar" ).hover(
    function() {
        $("#topBar").addClass("category_roll").css('background', 'rgba(201, 135, 2, 0.95)');
    }
);

$( "#topBar" ).mouseout(function() {
     $("#topBar").css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)');
});
```

See the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/fNac3/4/

Comment: Yea this will work fine. I guess it can't be done with pure css? I still need to fix this so that when you rollover topbar the color also changes.

Comment: also once I am using jquery why use the css3 transition at all and not just jquery to change the color?

Comment: @Sackling Yes you are quite right there, you actually do not need CSS3 trans for these things. You can do that with jquery itself. Will make your life much easier. As to, whether it can be done purely with CSS, I am not sure about it and even if it can be done , it will be a lot of hard work .

Comment: @Sackling See the updated fiddle  for the top bar fix : http://jsfiddle.net/fNac3/4/

Comment: Nice thanks for the fix. 1 more issue. what if I want to have multiple of these images on 1 page. is there a way to make this reusable without having to make a seperate query for each image?

Comment: What do you mean by separate query ?

Comment: I meant instead of copying the whole jquery code over and changing the id's to #img2 and #topbar2

Comment: To avoid this you have to dynamically pass ids of the elements where you have `mouseovered` . For eg : Create a function which takes the Ids on mouseuver/hover and then passes them on to the actual functions as explained in the fiddle. Don't forget to up vote  and accept the answer, if you think it answers your previous question :) .

Comment: marked as accepted :) thanks. I'm not sure how to dynamically pass the ids. What I was thinking was using the parent css selector maybe